# Raphael JS: Click is triggered at end of drag

Tags: javascript, raphael

The intent of the following code is to change the circle color only when you click on it, not on mouse up after a drag/drop. For some reason Raphael is firing a click event on mouse up. How to prevent this? 
This is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ps0604/7f2ez/2/)

This is the HTML:

```
<div id="canvas"></div>
```

And this is the javascript:

```
Raphael.st.draggable = function() {
  var me = this,
  lx = 0,
  ly = 0,
  ox = 0,
  oy = 0,
  moveFnc = function(dx, dy) {
      lx = dx + ox;
      ly = dy + oy;
      me.transform('t' + lx + ',' + ly);
  },
  startFnc = function() {},
  endFnc = function() {
      ox = lx;
      oy = ly;
  };

  this.drag(moveFnc, startFnc, endFnc);
};



var paper = Raphael(document.getElementById('canvas'));
var mySet = paper.set();

var c = mySet.push(paper.circle(50, 50, 50).attr('fill', 'red'));

mySet.draggable();

c.click(function(evt) {
   this.attr({"fill": "#2e2e2e" });
});
```

Comment: Why do you use set? Will you add more shapes? If you use one shape I have a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i'm using to drag sets:

http://jsfiddle.net/Margo/Q3EBw/5/

```
paper = Raphael(0, 0, 500, 500);
var ox = 0;
var oy = 0;
var screenSet = paper.set();
screenSet.push(paper.rect(0, 0, 100, 75, 0).attr({
        fill: 'red', stroke: 'none'
    }));

screenSet.push(paper.text(0 , 0 ,"Text").attr({ "text-anchor": "start" }));

    start = function() {

        ox =  this.attr("x");
        oy = this.attr("y");
        screenSet.attr({
            opacity: 1
        });
},

    move = function(dx, dy) {
        var att ={
            x: ox + dx,
            y:oy + dy
        };
        screenSet.attr(att);
    },
    up = function() {
        this.attr({
            opacity: .5
        });
        ox = 0, oy = 0;
    };
screenSet.drag(move, start, up);
```

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: That doesn't answer the question - at the end of your drag the element is still clicked.

Comment: Since it is an accepted answer i guess it did answer it...  no prevent event was needed when you use the drag functions to change  style and not using the click event.

Comment: Title of question is clearly says `Raphael JS: Click is triggered at end of drag`. Click is still triggered and this answer doesn't help the same quesition about click I have...